# Unity On Click error

Tags: unity-game-engine, onclick

TowerSelection class I think is working fine.

```
 public class TowerSelection : MonoBehaviour {

        public GameObject towerType;

        void Start()  {}

        void Update() {
        }

        public void TowerType (GameObject prefab) {
            towerType = prefab;
            Debug.Log (towerType.name);
        }

    }
```

TowerSpot class,  the problem is in OnMouseUp Method at  " prefabTower = GameObject.FindObject ... "

```
public class TowerSpot : MonoBehaviour {

    private GameObject prefabTower;

    private GameObject tower;
    private int gold;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void OnMouseUp()
    {
        if (placeTower())
        {

            **prefabTower = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<TowerSelection>().towerType;**

            Debug.Log (prefabTower.name);

            gold = GameManager.Manager.getGold();

            if (gold > 0)
            {
                Instantiate( prefabTower , this.transform.position, this.transform.rotation);
                GameManager.Manager.currentGold(-20);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("No hay suficiente dinero");
            }

        }


    }

    private bool placeTower()
    {
        return tower == null;
    }
}
```

This is the line I think it is returning "NULL", I have tried doing a lot of things but the error continues.

```
prefabTower = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<TowerSelection>().towerType;
```

The error is this one, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What I am doing is a tower defence game, I have 2 buttons depending on what tower I am selecting, tower 1 or tower 2, using On Click in the inspector I call the TowerType method and I add the tower's Prefab, but when using the method FindObjectOfType<>() It returns null everytime, and I dont know why.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

FindObjectOfType looks **in the scene** and returns the first occurrence of type T. Clearly there are no T objects in the scene (no towers) therefore the assumption that one must found is wrong, hence trying to retrieve the property produces the error.

Why are you doing this anyway? If you are trying to create a tower, that prefab should either be references in the script directly (assigned to a public var in the inspector) or fed via loading a resource at runtime.

Comment: Yes, I have already done it. I can place Towers where I want, but the problem now is that I want to add a chance to select what type of tower do you want to add to the scene. That's why I am doing this like that, in the first class I obtain the prefab that the player selects clicking the button from the canvas, if I click button 1 the button sends to the method typeTowers what Prefab has been selected by the player, and then in the other class I have to instantiate it. Here is where the error occurs. I add here a photo how I have configured the inspector, http://i.stack.imgur.com/BjBGq.png

Comment: You are on the wrong path from a logic perspective. You shouldn't instantiate a new object to change its type, a tower object should be flexible, driven by a property that tells the logic what type of tower that is, otherwise you end up with too many objects and too convoluted logic.